# Imapal query is very slow

Tags: impala

see the profile,we find the information about the slowest node:
BytesRead: 19.73 MB (20693313)
BytesReadDataNodeCache: 0
BytesReadLocal: 0

Hope to get some solutions
thank you

Comment: Could you please add, 1. the query? 2. input? 3. output?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.